# Not called at Start method of USB DriverKit

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I am writing a DriverKit dext and can activate it using System Extension framework. I have the entitlements in place for usb which is 
**com.apple.developer.driverkit** is set to **true**
**com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb** has been added as dictionary but without any sub values ( it is empty) .

I was expecting getting called at dext's Start method after any USB device being plugged in but I am not seeing any calls.

Any idea whether any step / configuration is missing ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of critical pieces of information you haven't shared:

- Is SIP disabled on your machine or have you got the necessary entitlements enabled in your signing certificate/provisioning profile?
- Why is your USB DriverKit entitlement empty? Apple will normally issue USB entitlements with a specific vendor ID, or a set of them.
- Is your dext activation (from the wrapper app) definitely succeeding?
- Are you getting any crash reports? (See Console.app)
- What exactly do you mean by "after **any** USB device being plugged in" (emphasis mine)? What is your dext's IOKit matching dictionary in the Info.plist? What devices do you expect it to match?
- Is your driver's service object showing up in the I/O Registry? (`ioreg` or `IORegistryExplorer.app`)

Those are common causes but to diagnose the problem regardless - have you looked at the system log? Specifically, `sysextd` and `kextd` will typically complain in the log when there is something about a dext which makes it not loadable.

Try something like this:

- Uninstall your dext
- Reboot
- `/Library/SystemExtensions` should not have any remnants of your dext. (in any uuid-named subdirectories) If it does, try running `sudo kextcache --invalidate /`, wait until that finishes, then reboot again. Zombie dexts cause major problems.
- Launch `log stream --info --predicate 'process == "kextd" || process == "sysextd" || processID == 0'` in a Terminal window (you might want to add your app to the predicate if you're logging via `NSLog`/`os_log` there too)
- Launch your app, install the dext
- Check if the log shows anything relevant
- Plug in your device
- Check if the log shows anything relevant

You *should* be seeing some useful information there. Feel free to update your question with the logs you get if you can't make sense of them.

Comment: my simple dext using com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci have similiar issues,  init() function is called,but system prompt process carsh. please help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874309/pci-driver-migrating-from-iokit-kext-to-driverkit-dext-issues